# Angular 2 place components depending on an array

Tags: angular, typescript

im new to angular 2 and i got stuck...
I try to create a board for a boardgame (reversi, board like chess but mono-color)
I have a class cellInfo(here i want to hold the infos)

```
constructor(row: number, col: number, stats: boolean[]){
  this.row = row;
  this.col = col;
  this.stats = stats;
}
```

I have a class courtInfo(here i create an array of cellinfo)

```
constructor(x: number){
  this.x = x;
  this.cells = new CellInfo[x];

  for(let row: number = 0; row < x; row++){
    this.cells[row] = new CellInfo[x];
    for(let col: number = 0; col < x; col++){
      this.cells[row][col] = new CellInfo(row, col, [false, false, false])
    }
  }
}
```

I have a component courtComonent

- in the .ts i create a courtInfo

  ```
  constructor() {this.round = new CourtInfo(8); }
  ```

(I named round cause later i want to refresh this array each round)

- in the html i tryed to create a component-object from class cellComponent

  ```
   div *ngFor="let cellrow of round.cells"

     div class = row; *ngFor="let cellcol of round.cells[cellrow]"

       div class = col

         cell></cell

       /div 

     /div

   /div
  ```

(please imagine the < and >

in the court.component.css i have this:

```
.row{
  --row-hight: 12,5%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--row-hight);
}
.col{
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
cell{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

the CellComponent itself shell be a div wich shell (later) draw a circle or not.

But atm this is not working, the cells are not added to the court. 
I dont know if i had to bind somewhere, i guessed that not cause the array [cells] is a class-intern...

Im seeking for some hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you construct the cell info doesn't make much sense. You are making both the rows and their values have the type of **CellInfo**, there are no arrays anywhere.

It should be more like this:

```js
constructor(x: number){
  this.x = x;
  this.cells = []; // the type of cells should be CellInfo[][]

  for(let row: number = 0; row < x; row++){
    this.cells[row] = []; // a row is just an array of CellInfo
    for(let col: number = 0; col < x; col++){
      // values are stored in the row array at the column position
      this.cells[row][col] = new CellInfo(row, col, [false, false, false]) 
    }
  }
}
```

After that you should be able to go trough them like this:

```html
 div *ngFor="let cellrow of round.cells"

   div class = row; *ngFor="let cellcol of cellrow"
```

First for goes trough the rows, the 2nd for gets the cells.